# jQuery getting new objects

Tags: jquery

When using jQuery functions like `replaceWith`, the function return-value is (as clearly documented), the *original* jQuery object. However, I commonly want to chain with the *replacement* jQuery object. How do I do this?

For example:

```
$("#original").replaceWith("<span id='replacement'></span>").someFn()
# this calls someFn() on #original, NOT as desired on #replacement.
```

What's the nicest way to fix this? Clearly I could do `$("#replacement").someFn()`, but that's not the point, as (for example) I may not know the id of the replacement element in advance.

NOTE: I'm also interested in feedback about the premise. eg, am I missing the point of jQuery and is there some idiom I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a plugin. In its simplest form it could be:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replace = function(target) {
        $(target).replaceWith(this);
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Usage:

```
$("<span id='replacement'></span>").replace("#original").someFn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#original").replaceWith($("<span id='replacement'></span>").someFn());
```

or

```
$("#original").replaceWith("<span id='replacement'></span>").filter("span").someFn()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the span beforehand in a variable then replace with that variable.

```
var $span = $('<span id="replacement"></span>');
$('#original').replaceWith($span);
$span.someFn();
```